# angular universal error. How to remove angular universal from build

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

After update angular and universal to version 9, I got an error when I did build with SSR.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\projects\my-app\header.component.html'
```

How can I remove universal from the build ? Or fix this error

Comment: Apologies for the obvious question, but have you checked whether `D:\projects\my-app\header.component.html` actually exists and that Node has access to it?

Comment: @ReiMavronicolas No, it does not exist there. my-app folder contains the following folders: src, dist, node_modules, e2e etc. It should not be there. It shows when I am running ` npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr `

Comment: Use this to fix Angular Universal error [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026178/angular-9-universal-error-component-headercomponent-is-not-resolved)