# npm run serve:ssr. ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'google/protobuf/api.proto'

Tags: angular-universal, protobuf.js

I'm trying to **migrate an existing angular app to use Server Side Rendering through Angular Universal**. npm build:ssr works without any problems, but when trying to serve:ssr, it errors when trying to find 'google/protobuf/api.proto' and the other protos.

The protos are in `node_modules/protobufjs/google...`, but apparently can't be found when trying to serve the site.

Some Google searching said I needed to put an `externalDependencies` but that hasn't worked.

version info:

````
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.0.7
Node: 13.12.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.0.5
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core                       9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics                 9.1.1
@angular/animations                        9.1.1
@angular/cdk                               9.1.1
@angular/cli                               9.0.7
@angular/elements                          9.1.1
@angular/fire                              5.4.2
@angular/flex-layout                       9.0.0-beta.29
@angular/material                          9.1.1
@angular/upgrade                           9.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                           9.0.7
@nguniversal/builders                      9.1.0
@nguniversal/common                        9.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine                9.1.0
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   8.2.6
@schematics/angular                        9.1.1
@schematics/update                         0.803.26
rxjs                                       6.5.5
typescript                                 3.7.5
webpack                                    4.41.2```
````

Answer (score 0):

If your using Angular Firestore you need to add it as a dependency. That's what worked for me, in your angular.json file.

```
 "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/TeacherKellyUKA/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "externalDependencies": ["@firebase/firestore"]
          },
```

If that doesn't work try this thread: [Angular 9 universal Error: Component 'HeaderComponent' is not resolved:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026178/angular-9-universal-error-component-headercomponent-is-not-resolved)